# Packaging Vue Components for npm with rollup and support JSX?

Tags: vue.js, jsx, bundle, bundler, rollup

I am following the [rollup guide](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/packaging-sfc-for-npm.html#Packaging-Components-for-npm) on packaging a Vue component.

my code contains some JSX code and no matter what I try the rollup build always
fails with

```
[!] (plugin commonjs) SyntaxError: Unexpected token (12:13) in /home/nt/Desktop/vue-text-highlight-v2/src/components/Hello.vue?rollup-plugin-vue=script.js
src/components/Hello.vue?rollup-plugin-vue=script.js (12:13)
10:   methods: {
11:     hello(){
12:       return <h1>Hi!</h1>
                 ^
13:     }
14:   },
```

I created a minimal sandbox with this minimal component only to display the use case
with all my roolup dependencies

[SandBox with all config and src files](https://codesandbox.io/s/icy-pond-wvtek?file=/src/index.js)

or

[Github repository with minimal example](https://github.com/ntedgi/vue-template-jsx)

**Hello.vue**

```
<template>
<span>
  {{ this.hello() }}
</span>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Hello',
  methods: {
    hello(){
      return <h1>Hi!</h1>
    }
  },
}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```